# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings returns null on POST but not on a GET request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We deployed on a existing server that was already setup and configured with another asp.net application.  This isn't something we normally do, as we setup on a new server and configure everything.  We also have this same ASP.NET application running on several other servers with no problems.

The application is MVC3 running on ASP.NET 4

The app uses controllers to create a simple RPC type of API.
Example: (Send) /Services/LMS/GetCourses (Returns) XML document

Once we deployed the asp.net application and had everything setup in IIS we ran into an issue we never seen before.

The application will send a NullReferenceException on the line below.

```
DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ProviderName);
```

But only if the http request is a POST.  If we send a GET request, it works.

I guessing this is some configuration conflict.  Is there something in a config file that could limit our application from reading our Web.config settings on a POST?

---

To provide more context based on comments:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Configuration;
using Services.Models;    
public class DBConnection
{
    protected DbProviderFactory factory;
    protected string connectionString;
    protected char paramChar; // could be ':' or '@' depending on database

    public DBConnection(string db) // db is equal to "LMS"
    {
        try
        {
            factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ProviderName); // the exception stack points to this line having NullReferenceException
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString;
            paramChar = DbUtil.GetParamChar(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ProviderName);
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("The database " + db + " has not been defined in the web.config file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does GetFactory do?  Are you sure that the null ref is happening when you attempt to read the Provider property?

Comment: Are you sure that `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ProviderName);` is executed during `GET` request? I don't think that error has soemthing related to POST request. What ProviderName have you specified in connectionstring in web.config?

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be related to a POST or GET.  But we have a html form for testing.  A POST using the URL /Services/LMS/GetCourses and the error occurs.  I copy and paste that URL into browser and hit enter (a GET request) and it works.

Comment: Your GET request fetches data from database? Also, what is the value of `ProviderName` in your web.config connectionstring?